# Transfer file from one android to another android as shareit, using java?

Tags: android, file-sharing

I am new in java and I want to transfer file from one device to another using java. I need the concept of broadcasting package from server and  how to receiver receive that package.

Comment: What do you mean "from server"? There is no server in p2p file sharing

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html